# Exhaust fumes visible in car

Tags: exhaust, leak

I recently bought a diesel Jaguar S-Type. It was fine until 2 days ago when I could smell exhaust fumes in the car. Today, when out driving, I could see the fumes in the car.

1. What could be causing this?
2. What should I do?

Comment: Most likely a leak, put the car on ramps and try to find where it is leaking from

Answer (score 3):

Apply some back pressure to the exhaust by lightly holding a rag over the exhaust tip and have someone listen and check the engine bay for leaks.

If there is no leaks in the exhaust it could be injector seals, a smell of exhaust is quite a common symptom before they start making a chuffing sound. When the engine's running pour some soapy water around each injector to see if they produce bubbles.